# How to send erc20 token from my metamask wallet to other address without private key?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js, erc20

I'm going to send erc20 token to other metamask wallet address in node.js.
Now I can send erc20 token using my wallet private key.
But I want to send it without private key.
How can I do for it?
Please Help me!

Answer (score 0):

To send a transaction, you need an account. To sign a transaction from this account, you need a private key. Therefore, you will need some kind of account with a private key.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Privatekey is not required when transfort erc20 token via Metamask.
I would like to implement it in a way that Metamask sends tokens.
What should I do?